# Chrome browser showing two different print preview from two different buttons

Tags: google-chrome, printing, preview

I have been working on an application where on the page there are two buttons for printing an invoice. The button triggers to print the same invoice. The issue is that i am getting two different print preview on the chrome browser as well as when i am printing its output through printer.

One preview is showing zoom-out view and the other having zoomed-in view.

Attached are the snapshot and code for the two.

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thankyou.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Is that two buttons on one page, or two separate pages? Is there any CSS with media queries associated with the printing?

Comment: These two buttons are on a single page. One is an anchor tag and the other is a button tag with type button. I used the same code for both location button, but the output was same. Yes have written some print css for @page and for elements to hide while printing.